# PDF file opened with LibreOffice, now conversion to Word needed

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, libreoffice

Of all the software I ever tried to handle PDF files, I found LibreOffice by far the best (at least for the files tested). The number of codes when importing the odg file into DVX2 (this is a CAT tool) is insignificant, so I get an almost pure and code-free document. Initial import of the PDF into DVX2, ca. 2000 codes, export as RTF handled via CodeZapper, 800 codes. Opening the PDF with LibreOffice, then importing the resulting file in DVX2 12 (twelve) codes!!!

The problem comes at the end. The client wants me to send the translation in Word, and LibreOffice refuses to save the file with "odg" extension to Word or RTF format. Any idea how I could circumvent this?

Comment: What version of Office do you use? Do you have access to Adobe Acrobat XI, what is the specifc error you get when you try to save the file as a .docx file.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you use such things but there is an excellent free site that can handle this.

www.convertfiles.com can convert virtually any format, including .odg.

bem